# multiple XML serilizations on same object in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, serialization, xml-serialization

I have Prospect and contact classes. I need to use serialized prospect in 2 diff places in 2 diff formats. The first format is achieved using the XML Serialization's API methods. for the second one, I have to display the prospect for editor and it has diff schema.  all the attributes are displayed as independent elements such as below XML.

Format#1

```
    <prospect>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <REPNAME>TEST</REPNAME>
    <contact> 
        <FNAME>TEST-FNAME</FNAME>
        <LNAME>TEST-LNAME</LNAME>
    </contact>
</prospect>
```

Format #2

```
    <prospect>
    <Elemant Name="ID" value="1" />
    <Element Name="REPNAME" value="TEST" />
    <contact>
        <Element Name="FNAME" value="TEST-FNAME" />
        <Element Name="LNAME" value="TEST-LNAME" />
    </contact>
</prospect>

[XmlElement(Prospect)]
public class prospect 
{
   private string id, repName;
   private contact c;


     [xmlElement(PID)]
     public string ID {}

     [xmlElement(RepresentName)]
     public string REPNAME {}
}

[XmlElement(Contact)]
public contact Con
{
     private string fname,lname;
     [xmlElement(FirstName)]
     public string FNAME {}

     [xmlElement(LastName)]
     public string LNAME {}
}
```

My question is - by adding Element (seializable) type Prospect & Contact classes, can I achieve 2 diff formats of serialized XML? what do I need to do? I should be able to transform between the 2 formats. I dont want to add new set of data objects to achieve 2 formats. If i have write a xml custom seriliazer, what is best bet among all these options.

Answer (score 0):

You must write a custom serializer for two different serilization. If you want to serialize the all your classes in only one class, you can write a generic serilization class. To do this, you can use the XmlSerializer class in System.Xml.Serilization namespace.

Sample Code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
```

**For more information and sample:**

http://csharpexamples.com/c-generic-xml-serilization/